# How to send variable from one function to another?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter Framefork, and I insert data to database and next I want to do is to take from table, value of `Id` I just insert using `mysql_insert_id();`, and insert this value of `Id` to another table.
**My code in Controller**

```
public function insert_data_to_db(){



    $form_data_book_name['BookName'] = $this->input->post('BookName');


            $this->book_model->insert_books_to_db($form_data_book_name);


            }
```

**And my Model function **

```
public function insert_books_to_db($form_data_book_name){
        $b = $this->db->insert('book',$form_data_book_name);
        $id = mysql_insert_id();


        return $b;
    }
```

So, the question is how I can take this `$id` from `function insert_books_to_db` and insert it to another function like this:

```
public function insert_id($id){
$result = $this->db->insert('table_with_id',$id);
return $result;
}
```

ow recive this $id in my Controller and next pass it again to the model function insert_id()?

Comment: Ahem, `return $id;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return an array containing the book and the id, access on the controller level like any other array.

```
public function insert_data_to_db(){
    $form_data_book_name['BookName'] = $this->input->post('BookName');
    $data = $this->book_model->insert_books_to_db($form_data_book_name);
    echo $data['Id'];
    print_r($data);
}
public function insert_books_to_db($form_data_book_name){
    $b = $this->db->insert('book',$form_data_book_name);
    $output=array();
    $output['Id']= mysql_insert_id();
    $output['book']=$b;
    return $output;
}
```